# How to merge in data from another DataFrame that contains a match on a substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a DataFrame 'main_df':

```
 ID    Data1    Data2
123        1        2
456        1        2
789        1        2
```

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Data1', 'Data2'], data=[['123', '1', '2'], ['456', '1', '2'], ['789', '1', '2']])
```

I want to merge in other data from 'other_df' which does not contain all IDs and also has some text cluttering the ID field:

```
RawData
123XXX FooBar
456XXX MooCar
```

```
other_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['RawData'], data=[['123XXX FooBar'], ['456XXX MooCar']])
```

How can I merge in the data from 'other_df' into 'main_df' based on the ID match given the substring in RawData for chars 0-3?

Desired result:

```
 ID    Data1    Data2           RawData
123        1        2     123XXX FooBar
456        1        2     456XXX MooCar
789        1        2
```

Comment: break down your problem: how would you normally merge dfs? now work out the steps to get to that point. and please read [ask] very carefully

Comment: `df.merge(df2.assign(ID=df2["RawData"].str[:3]), on="ID", how="outer")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use str.slice on the `RawData` column to create a new column, then merge the dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
main_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Data1', 'Data2'], data=[['123', '1', '2'], ['456', '1', '2'], ['789', '1', '2']])

other_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['RawData'], data=[['123XXX FooBar'], ['456XXX MooCar']])

other_df['prefix'] = other_df['RawData'].str.slice(0, 3)

merged_df = main_df.merge(other_df, left_on = 'ID', right_on='prefix', how='left')

merged_df = merged_df.drop(columns='prefix')

print(merged_df)
```

returns

```
    ID Data1 Data2        RawData
0  123     1     2  123XXX FooBar
1  456     1     2  456XXX MooCar
2  789     1     2            NaN
```

Comment: any reason you create a new df called 'merged_df'? can you overwrite main_df with no issue?

Comment: @Barry you could replace merged_df to main_df. You can overwrite with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the substring is going to be the first three characters, you can create a new column which only contains the first three characters and use that as your key for merging

```py
In [8]: main_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Data1', 'Data2'], data=[['123', '1', '2'], ['456', '1', '2'], ['789', '1', '2']])

In [9]: other_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['RawData'], data=[['123XXX FooBar'], ['456XXX MooCar']])

In [10]: other_df['ID'] = other_df['RawData'].apply(lambda x: x[:3])

In [13]: merged_df = pd.merge(main_df, other_df, on='ID', how='left')

In [14]: merged_df
Out[14]:
    ID Data1 Data2        RawData
0  123     1     2  123XXX FooBar
1  456     1     2  456XXX MooCar
2  789     1     2            NaN
```

If you are simply looking for the any substring of "ID" in the "RawData" column, then the logic is a bit trickier but can still be done just by making the `lambda x:` slightly more sophisticated in the apply() step. If that is the problem you are trying to solve, let me know and I can put up a solution to that as well